# Does NancyFX support debugging Razor Views?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, razor, nancy

I setup a NancyFX project with Razor support as ASP.NET hosted. I use Visual Studio 2012. When I try to debug it just doesn't allow. The breakpoint indicator is not enabled when I attach to w3wp process. I double checked debug="true" attributes in web.config and existence of .pdb files in bin folder.

So does NancyFX really support debugging views?

P.S.
Debugging works fine in Modules, Bootstrap etc

Comment: It would be helpful to say HOW it's not allowed.  Is a button that you expect to be enbled, disabled?  Does it just not stop at a breakpoint you set?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint it always disabled when I attach VS to w3wp process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just isn't possible with Nancy.

<strike>Nancy uses a custom build of Razor because of the licensing and the hacks involved in getting intellisense working. So it's just not possible to get debugging working.</strike>

Having said that, if you need to debug in your views then it probably means your views are too complicated to begin with.

In the scenario of "Should I display this 'next' paging button"

You would want to add a property to your view which turns the conditions to a boolean.

That way your view becomes nothing more than conditional markup like:

`@if (Model.ShouldShowNextPage) {...}`

Then you can unit test all your routes and assert that the paging is enabled/disabled as intended.

**Edit:**

Nancy now uses the official packages for Razor, I personally did the work for this a few months ago. It currently supports V2.2 and V3.

If you're using .NET 4.0 you're stuck on 2.2 packages since 3.0 is built against .NET 4.5 despite the fact it uses nothing from .NET 4.5

The rest of my answer is still valid.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.ReSharper

This plugin (if you're using ReSharper), aids with basic intellisense that is helpful.

Comment: this answer is no longer true because ms open sourced the Razor codebase

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl you're correct and I have already published (few months ago) the changes to Nancy to use the real Razor packages. No more recompiled due to licensing issues.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl no that's awesome thanks, I forgot I answered this question so you've given me the opportunity to update my answer :) thanks a lot!